# How to extract specific values from a file in tcl

Tags: tcl

```
$$ comments             //not needed
$$ comments             /not needed   
$$
$$
$$ comments             //not needed
$$.INPUT a vcc            // needed 
$$.OUTPUT o                //needed 
$$.sdsds                        
$$
$$.sdsds 
$$ 
$$.sdsdsds

Mg1.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$nnn //needed
Mg1.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=6 $$nnn  //needed
```

here are no spaces between lines $$

Answer (score 4):

This is the sort of situation where a regular expression or a string format can help. However, it's not immediately clear what the format of the file is from the sample given; it's hard to tell exactly which bits are interesting, what the scope of variation in particular pieces is, etc. Still, we can take a few steps:

```
proc parseFileContents {contents infoVar} {
    upvar 1 $infoVar inf
    set lineNum 0
    foreach line [split $contents "\n"] {
        incr lineNum
        # Skip comment lines (?)
        if {[string match {$*} $line} continue
        # Skip blank lines
        if {[string trim $line] eq ""} continue
        # Parse a "real" line
        if {[scan $line "%s%s%s%s%s%s%f%f%s%s" a b c name d e value f g h] == 10} {
            set inf($name) $value
        } else {
            # Oh dear, didn't work!
            puts "warning: did not understand line $lineNum\n$line"
        }
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
parseFileContents $theContentsOfTheFile data
puts "Keys: [array names data]"
puts "VSS: $data(vss)"
puts "VCC: $data(vcc)"
```

As noted, a regular expression could also work for parsing the data line, using `regexp` instead of `scan` to do the matching, but I don't understand the format well enough to be able to say what RE to use.

Comment: @DKF - I hereby promise to never post another answer about Tcl :-) you always beat me to it, and write better answers at that. We all appreciate your time and knowledge - Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nir: practice practice practice :-)

Comment: +1 and Respect to both, the question looked like gibberish to me, let alone solve it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several libraries to process plain text files in the [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/) project and I'd recommend you look there.

If you insist on writing one yourself you can use something like this:

```
 set fd [open $filename r]
 while { [gets $fd line] >= 0 } {
       set data [split $line]
       if { [lindex $data 0] == {$} } { 
                  continue; #this is a comment line 
       }
       puts [lindex $line 3]; #or whatever index you need...
 }
 close $fp
```

EDIT: but please see Donal's answer as i find it better then my own.